# How to randomly select elements from subset of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe in the following form:

`W1 W2 W3 W4
 0  1  1  0
 1  1  1  1
 1  0  0  0
 0  1  0  1`

For every row, I want to randomly select single element that is **1** and make other ones zero. Initial zeros stay zeros E.g.

`W1 W2 W3 W4
 0  1  0  0
 0  1  0  0
 1  0  0  0
 0  0  0  1`

I have very convoluted solution that uses `iterrows()`, but I'm looking for a pandastic one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to randomly select 1 from every row and make the rest 0. Here's one approach. Sample the indices and based on indices assign 1. i.e

```
idx = pd.DataFrame(np.stack(np.where(df==1))).T.groupby(0).apply(lambda x: x.sample(1)).values
# array([[0, 2],
#        [1, 1],
#        [2, 0],
#        [3, 3]])

ndf = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(df.shape),columns=df.columns)

ndf.values[idx[:,0],idx[:,1]] = 1

   W1  W2  W3  W4
0   0   0   1   0
1   1   0   0   0
2   1   0   0   0
3   0   1   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks! How about solution that doesn't use numpy?

Comment: @QuantChristo I made it as pandastic as possible. Good luck

Comment: I wonder if it is possible or simpler with following trick: I draw random 1 in every row and change it to 2. Subsequently I change 1 to 0 and 2 back to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Idea is extract positions, shuffling and then remove duplicates by first column `0` - by rows:

```
#get positions of 1
a = np.where(df == 1)

#create nd array
X = np.hstack((a[0][:, None], a[1][:, None]))
#shuffling
np.random.shuffle(X)

#remove duplicates
vals = pd.DataFrame(X).drop_duplicates(0).values

#set 1
arr = np.zeros(df.shape)
arr[vals[:,0],vals[:,1]] = 1

df = pd.DataFrame(arr.astype(int), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
print (df)
   W1  W2  W3  W4
0   0   0   1   0
1   0   0   0   1
2   1   0   0   0
3   0   1   0   0
```

Comment: I dont think this is what op wanted

Comment: @Dark - Why do you think?

Comment: If I understand correctly he wants to keep only 1 one selected randomly in every row.

Comment: @Dark - Not sure if understand, be free post answer.

Comment: I have posted my answer based on my understanding of the question.

Comment: Yeah Op want to keep the initial zeros as it is and select the random ones from every row. You might come up with simpler answer :)

Comment: @Dark - I think now understand.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not exactly what I want. At every row I'm looking at "1" and randomly select one, other 1 are made into 0. So in result dataframe for every row should be only one "1". I assume that at least one "1" exists in every row.

Comment: @QuantChristo - Yes, just realised it.

Comment: @QuantChristo - I try find solution for it.

Comment: @jezrael - Thanks a lot! Stackoverflow should improve refreshing of comments ;)

Comment: @QuantChristo - Check edited answer, shoud be faster as `groupby` solution.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks! I wonder if it is possible or simpler with following trick: I draw random 1 in every row and change it to 2. Subsequently I change 1 to 0 and 2 back to 1.

Comment: @QuantChristo - You r question is interesting, need some faster solution? Or simplier?

Comment: @jezrael Simpler. Anyway, yours is much shorter and less convoluted than mine :)

Comment: @QuantChristo - hmmm, I try looking for some solution, I dont like `duplicated` parts, I try simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is mixture of functional and pandastic approach:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'w1': [0, 1,1,0],
                   'w2': [1, 1,0,1],
                   'w3': [1, 1,0,0],
                   'w4': [0, 1,0,1]})
df
   w1  w2  w3  w4
0   0   1   1   0
1   1   1   1   1
2   1   0   0   0
3   0   1   0   1


def choose_one(row):
    """
    returns array with randomly chosen positive value and 0 otherwise
    """
    one = np.random.choice([i for i, v in enumerate(row) if v])
    return [0 if i != one else 1 for i in range(len(row))]
```

apply for each row

```
df.apply(choose_one, 1)

   w1  w2  w3  w4
0   0   1   0   0
1   0   1   0   0
2   1   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   1
```